# Can **compasses** stand alone?

Tags: word-choice

Just wondering, does **compasses** can stand on its own?  Or should it be accompanied by **a pair of**?

Comment: What is the context you're considering? "Pass me those compasses" may well be more acceptable than "Pass me that pair of compasses"; other situations may require "pair of".

Comment: One might say that one e.g. constructed a figure, or measured a distance on a map "using compasses".

Comment: According to my dictionary, the instrument for drawing circles is called either *compass* or *pair of compasses*. I presume *compasses* alone would be plural, i.e. same as *pairs of compasses*.

Answer (score 1):

Today, people generally use the singular *compass* rather than *pair of compasses* for the instrument for drawing circles.

However, back when people used *pair of compasses*, it could be shortened to *compasses*, the same way we shorten *pair of scissors* to *scissors* or *pair of pliers* to *pliers* today.

For evidence, consider this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ruler+and+pair+of+compasses%2Cruler+and+a+pair+of%2C+ruler+and+compasses%2C+a+pair+of+compasses&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cruler%20and%20pair%20of%20compasses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cruler%20and%20a%20pair%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cruler%20and%20compasses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20pair%20of%20compasses%3B%2Cc0). It shows that *ruler and compasses* was not that much less frequent than *a pair of compasses*, and much more frequent than either *ruler and a pair of compasses* or *ruler and pair of compasses*